# TypeError: getCreators() is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script going through every calendar I have access to, one by one, and adding the events to an array. The goal is to take all of the events and put them in the same set of columns, with one of the columns being the name of the creator of the event. I'm sure I'm messing up something simple here, but I'm mainly copying the code from the CloudBakers.com example sheet here: https://www.cloudbakers.com/blog/export-google-calendar-entries-to-a-google-spreadsheet

Here is the code I have:

```
function allCal(){
  var events = "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1q5a29MtZz0zzQQ4F8hpsigkZGtCeK7qIh3tGLAZbgPg');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calendars').activate();
  var today = new Date();
  var endDate = new Date(today.getTime() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var cals = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  for (var i=0;i<cals.length;i++){
    var cal = cals[i];
    var calId = cal.getId();
    events += cal.getEvents(today, endDate);
  }
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+1;
var details=[[calId,events[i].getCreators(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,16,1,4);
range.setValues(details);
  }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `events` is not an array, it is a string. So `events[i]` is referring to the ith character of that string, which does not have a method called `getCreators()` on it.

I suggest changing the declaration of `events` to `var events = [];` and changing the line where you append events to something more like `events.push(cal.getEvents(today, endDate));`

**UPDATE**

On further inspection, I would assume that `getEvents()` is returning an array of objects. If that is the case, you would need to change that line to something like this instead.

```
events.push(...cal.getEvents(today, endDate));
```

This uses the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator (the `...`) to push each element of the array returned onto the `events` array. Alternatively, you could use [`array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), but this way seems a little more idiomatic to me.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I have made the changes as suggested, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Then I would be suspicious of what `cal.getEvents()` is returning. It may not be an object that has a `getCreators()` method on it.

Comment: I had a thought, and updated my solution to explain.

Comment: This fixed it. I'm running into a new, unrelated error now but this cleared up this issue. Thanks so much!